# The virtual path maps to another application, which is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have VS2013

- SolutionProject

  - Web Application 1 > UC Folder > UserControl.ascx
  - Web Application 2 > Form Folder > Form1.aspx  (<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ucSelector" Src="~/SolutionProject/Web Application 1/UC Folder/UserControl.ascx"%>)

I've got this error message "The virtual path '/SolutionProject/Web Application 1/UC Folder/UserControl.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed", When I call UserControl in Form1.aspx no matter how I try to use with "~" or without "~".

"Web Application 1" > Reference  > "Web Application 2"

"Web Application 2" cannot reference to "Web Application 1" because of my project scenarios.

Is there any solutions to use usercontorls web application in different web appilcation within one solution project.

Thanks,

June